# Role of connection in Lagrangian of a field theory

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, field-theory, action

I understand some of the basics of differential geometry. I have two questions about gauge theory from the physical perspective:

- I understand the connection is literally a "connection" between fibers, a horizontal tangent space, to provide the parallel transport of a lifted point to its endpoint based on the curve it gets lifted from. I know this is also a 1 form on the fibres themselves, and takes the value of a Lie algebra when these fibres are principle fibers. In what way is this connection a Lagrangian? What physical features do they share?
- Following this, the parallel transport is the integral of a connection. I think I am clear on why this is, because of covariant derivatives and whatnot, but what physical intuition do we have for this being the action?

Obviously this is in a classical field, else we would have action $\to$ path integral - I think - and I would accept either a general answer or a specific case study. For example, in an electromagnetic field.

Comment: The Lagrangian takes in a connection and outputs a number. If you integrate the Lagrangian over all of space, you get the action. Connections which extremize the action are solutions to the classical equations of motion.

Comment: Ok, I follow you. Is this what is called a gauge transformation on the G fibres? Putting a connection into L and giving back a number?

Comment: No. Look up the "principle of least action" in physics, which is a very general thing. If you have some system, maybe a ball moving near earth's surface, if you fix the start point and end point of the ball, and the time interval it takes to travel from one point to the other, the path the ball takes will be the one which minimizes a functional of the paths called the "action." In other words, the "action" for system gives the dynamics, or the "equations of motion," saying how the system will evolve in one moment of time to the next.

Comment: In a standard yang mills gauge theory, the lagrangian is $L = -\tfrac{1}{4} Tr( F^{\mu \nu} F_{\mu \nu}) $ and the action is $S = \int d^4 x L$.

Comment: I know about least action, sorry for explaining myself poorly. I mean why is the connection what goes into the lagrangian? I thought it was related to the symmetry of the group, because usually a term like this shows up in L. What is the physical meaning of the connection, beyond a connection between different vertical fibres?

Comment: I guess its because it restores our idea of variation, because we can parallel transport (consider different paths)?

Comment: Ah, okay. There are two things at play here: matter and forces. The connection should be thought of as a field which is responsible for a force. In the $U(1)$ case, the connection $A_\mu dx^\mu$ is the vector potential of the electromagnetic field. The matter field will be an associated bundle to your $G$ bundle. So if you have an electron field, that is an associated bundle to your principle $U(1)$ bundle. Note that in order to construct an associated bundle you must choose a representation of $G$. For $U(1)$ these are given by integers, i.e. integer multiples of the unit electric charge $e$.

Comment: What do you mean by "In what way is this connection a Lagrangian?" and for the integral of the connection (Wilson line or parallel transport) being an action? Almost always the local connection 1-form $A$ enters in the Lagrangian (e.g. by minimal coupling $\partial_\mu \mapsto \partial_\mu - i q A $ to turn a global symmetry into a local one) but it is not the Lagrangian itself.

Comment: This is confusing me a bit more, to be honest. Mathematically, the connection giving us a force makes sense, since the connection is valued like a Lie algebra 1 form which roughly gives us a vector field. I still lack some physical intuition for why this should be related to the lagrangian at all. Especially since this sounds like a potential and the parallel transport/holonomy is usually given as the kinetic action. And the connection enters the lagrangian as a symmetry condition after all?

Comment: Is there a complete reference I can look at that builds the physics of this (I guess the opposite of being aimed at physicists who are interested in math)?

Comment: Something which you may find helpful is the following statement(s): the Wilson loops (holonomies in math language) give the complete set of gauge invariants (this is often used in the lattice qft literature for calculations and tilings). If you take the lowest order expansion of the loop, the result is essentially the F^2 appearing in the action, so it's simply the lowest order invariant we can build. The appearance of the connection elsewhere can be understood as the relation between the (spacetime) differential and frame fields.